# Python speech recognition software with Google's API in noise

Tags: python, api, speech-recognition

I have recently set a project for me with Python, create a script that is voice controlled.

I have been using googles API to do this, but with using this API, I notice that it never stops listening unless it is completely quiet, which stops you from running commands in even somewhat noisy areas or with people talking around.

Here is what I have:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx
r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx.init()
listen = False

# Define methods

while True:
while listen == False:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        if (r.recognize(audio) == "start") :
            listen = True
            print("Listening...")
            break
        else:
            continue
    except LookupError:
        continue

while listen == True:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    print("1")
    try:
        print("2")
        if (r.recognize(audio) == "stop") :
            listen = False
            print("Listening stopped. Goodnight")
            break
        else:
            print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))
    except LookupError:
        engine.say('Audio cannot be read!')
        engine.runAndWait()
        print("Could not understand audio")
```

Imported PYTTSX and SpeechRecognition(uses googles API). Now how would I get this to run more like Google Now, where I can say anything, in any situation, with background noise or not, and have it stop listening when I am done talking? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Voice Recognition Library - Always Listen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394329/python-voice-recognition-library-always-listen)

Comment: Like google now for listening in noise you need keyword spotting solution provided in the answer to the question above. It can work in noise, it will only react on a specific keyphrase.

Comment: Okay that seems to be what I am looking for, but I am unable to find a PocketSphinx for Windows 7.

Comment: @Mikolay I msg'd you on Sourceforge.

Comment: You can download it here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyPocketSphinx/12608

Answer (score 0):

I have just tweaked your code a while, it works fine now. Sorry for not being pythonic I am new to python:
here "pinger" is a temp variable for holding audio
and you should use String.lower() to convert the string obtained from google to lower character so that it matches the test string.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx
r = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx.init()
listen = False

# Define methods

while True:
    while listen == False:
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                audio = r.listen(source)
                pinger=r.recognize_google(audio)
            try:
                if (pinger.lower() == "start") :
                    listen = True
                    print("Listening...")
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            except LookupError:
                continue
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            continue

    while listen == True:
        print "2nd part"
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
                audio = r.listen(source)
                pinger=r.recognize_google(audio)
            print("1")

            print("2")
            if (pinger.lower() == "stop") :
                listen = False
                print("Listening stopped. Goodnight")
                break
            else:
                print("You said " + pinger)
        except LookupError:
            engine.say('Audio cannot be read!')
            engine.runAndWait()
            print("Could not understand audio")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
            continue
        except sr.RequestError:
            print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service")
            continue
```